# Add Modal Popup for each chart.js data value

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, chart.js

Is there any way to add modal popup for each chart js data values. Here dD 1 , dD2 etc... are the data values, on click this each value, i need to open modal popup.

```js
var dData = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 90) + 10
};
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["dD 1", "dD 2", "dD 3", "dD 4", "dD 5", "dD 6", "dD 7", "dD 8", "dD 9", "dD 10"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(0,60,100,1)",
    strokeColor: "black",
    data: [dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData()]
  }]
}

var index = 11;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var barChartDemo = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
  responsive: true,
  barValueSpacing: 2
});
setInterval(function() {
  barChartDemo.removeData();
  barChartDemo.addData([dData()], "dD " + index);
  index++;
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add model pop code here,

```
$("#canvas").click( 
    function(evt){
        var activePoints = myNewChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);           
        /* do something */
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. after add this script, when click on each bar i get an script error in console.
"canvas is not defined(…)", could you implement modal on each bar in above snippet.

Comment: look in console, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahidaparth7/1rpn77by/). On click of bars I have console the data from bar@sid